# Deserializing a JSON object using gson when keys are not known in advance

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse a JSON object which consists of an Array of Customer objects.   Each customer object contains a number of key/value pairs:

```
{
   "Customers": 
   [
     {
        "customer.name": "acme corp",
        "some_key": "value",
        "other_key": "other_value",
        "another_key": "another value"
     },
     {
        "customer.name": "bluechip",
        "different_key": "value",
        "foo_key": "other_value",
        "baa": "another value"
     }
   ]
}
```

The complication is that the keys are not known to me in advance.  A second complication is that the keys contain periods (.) that mean that even when I have tried to map them to a field, it fails.

I have been trying to map these to a Customers class:

```
Customers data = new Gson().fromJson(responseStr, Customers.class);
```

which looks like this:

```
public class Customers {

    public List<Customer> Customers;

    static public class Customer {

        public List<KeyValuePair> properties;
        public class KeyValuePair {
            String key;
            Object value;
        }     
    }
}
```

My problem is that in when I load this class from the JSON, my Customers list populates, but their properties are null.  How can I make GSON deal with the fact that I don't know the key names?

I have tried various other approaches including putting a HashMap in the Customer class, in place of the KeyValuePair class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach is that, you can create a Map of key values from the JSON and then look for the values, since the keys are not known

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String,List<Map<String, String>>>>() {}.getType();
    Map<String,List<Map<String, String>> >map = gson.fromJson(responseStr, mapType);
    System.out.println(map);

    Customers c = new Customers();

    c.setCustomers(map.get("Customers"));

    System.out.println(c.getCustomers());
```

Modify your Customers class like this

```
public class Customers {

public List<Map<String, String>> customers;

public List<Map<String, String>> getCustomers() {
    return customers;
}

public void setCustomers(List<Map<String, String>> customers) {
    this.customers = customers;
}

}
```